# Removing seconds from the time field in MS Access without updating the table

Tags: sql, ms-access, timestamp

Good day

I have a table that has users and time-stamps. I need to calculate how many users used a system at any given time. This will help to see peak hours. The problem is that seconds are separating my count(s). For instance, I'll have 4 of the same time-stamps[11:45,11:45, 11:45] because for the different seconds. Is there a way to remove them without updating the table. All the formatting functions don't work! Thanks in advance

The code is as follows;

```
SELECT distinct mid(Format (u.time), 1,5) as Time,
(select count(u1.student_id) from uselog u1 where u1.time = u.time) as users FROM uselog u
```

Comment: An example of your code would probably be helpful. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code has been added

Answer (score 0):

Just round off the seconds:

```
Select Distinct
    TimeSerial(Hour(u.time), Minute(u.time), 0) As [time],
    (Select Count("*") From uselog As u1 Where TimeSerial(Hour(u1.time), Minute(u1.time), 0) = u.time) As users 
FROM 
    uselog As u
```

Comment: Select Distinct
    TimeSerial(Hour(u.time), Minute(u.time), 0) As "time", count (u.student_id) as users 
    
FROM 
    uselog As u
GROUP BY TimeSerial(Hour(u.time), Minute(u.time), 0);  The one with the sub select caused MS Access to freeze, but thanks for the solution

Comment: Well, the sub wasn't my idea. Looked strange to me.